# Avoiding rasterization with svg image so that transforms work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, transform

I want to apply a `matrix` `transform`ation to an `svg`. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/godawnpL/). On Firefox, it looks like this:

[image: Blurry transform on Firefox]

It looks like it's rasterizing it to a 10x10 bitmap before transforming it because of my viewbox. How can I avoid this?

The way I see it, I can try to find a way to force Firefox not to rasterize, or use some form of embedding. (`<embed>`? `<object>`? `iframe`? I thought these were all bad practice for one reason or another.) I am loading these SVGs dynamically with JavaScript. How would I do that, then?

PS: If there's a way with [svg.js](https://svgjs.dev/), that's what I'm using right now, but I'm more than willing to go vanilla to just get this working.

EDIT: FWIW, apparently it's fixed in the nightly Firefox, but I'd still like a solution for now; I'm trying to roll out soon. (Also realized I haven't explicitly stated that it works in Chrome and IE)

Comment: It's fixed in the nightlies so try either beta or developer edition https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/ as it might be fixed there, if not it's certainly fixed here: https://nightly.mozilla.org/

Comment: Wow, thanks. Unfortunately I want this to work soon :) Try'na release a game that's fully developed in Chrome save this.

Comment: Releases are every 6 weeks. Did you try Beta?

Comment: Yeah, beta looks beauteous! June 23rd... Hm... is it worth the wait? :)

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to make the "original size" larger and adjust the transform to scale down by the same ratio.

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 20 20">
    <image xlink:href="https://www.adobe.com/inspire-apps/exporting-svg-illustrator-0913/fig11/img/napoleon%20for%20svg%201.svg"
           width="100" height="100" transform="matrix(0.1, 0.02, 0.02, 0.1, 1, 2)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did see this as an option. It is not ideal for me, because I have complex matrix calculations, but knowing that the end is in sight, I think I will do this as a hack for a month.